# Flutter: How to convert Object? to Map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, object

I'm using sharedPrefs to store some data. I stored Map like this `Map<String, String> map = {'test1':'test2'};`. After I save it locally `_sharedPrefsStore.write(PrefsKeys.testMapSave, map);` When I try to read it `var savedMap = _sharedPrefsStore.read(PrefsKeys.testMapSave,valueParser: (value) => value);` savedMap is Object?. When printed I get the my saved values `{test1 : test2}`. It displays my saved variable and key as map, but its Object?. How can I convert this Object? to Map?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing your Map as it is, save it as a String using `json.encode(yourMap)`.

To store:

```
_sharedPrefsStore.setString(PrefsKeys.testMapSave, json.encode(myMap));
```

To read:
create a method to parse a json decoded map and then

```
String myJson = _sharedPrefsStore.getString(PrefsKeys.testMapSave);
Map<String, String> myMap = jsonParsingMethod(myJson);
```

Comment: My write method already encodes it and read method decodes it before returning it's value